# What does one call a NON-wireless router?

Tags: router, terminology

I want to buy a simple ethernet router. Every online store I try I get those that include Wi-Fi. Still I can explicitly state that I want Wi-Fi, I can't state that I only want a non-Wi-Fi router. Is there a specific name for those type of routers?

Comment: Would this question maybe be more fit on english.se?

Comment: Many routers these days are hybrids that have Wi-Fi as well as ethernet ports to support wired connections. Usually you can just not enable the Wi-Fi capabilities if you don't need or want them. The price difference may not be very significant, so don't rule Wi-Fi capable ones out -- besides that, your needs could change in the future, plus it might be easier to sell if you want to get rid of it later on.

Comment: Cisco ASA-5505 is a small-home office firewall/router. No extras. There are plenty of firewall/routers out there that are less expensive. NetGear FVS series for example.

Answer (score 3):

It is simply called a "router."  In this day, its hard to find a home router without wireless, as it is what people most often want.

I did my own search on Newegg.com and found that "wired router" gave me better results for non-wireless routers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just call it an Ethernet router.

http://www.koshh.com/d-link-dsl-2520u-adsl2-ethernet-usb-combo-router.html

This model seems to do what you want.

Thomson (also known as speedtouch) from alcatel, also had those kind of routers. I din't find the official website though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking on NewEgg, they have a [`Wired Routers`](http://www.newegg.com/Wired-Routers/SubCategory/ID-28) section.

As for other websites, I would stick with trying to search by the term `Wired Router` (such as this [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=wired%20router) search).